# Why are my images received as string? (ROS)

Tags: ros

I already found my mistake. Should I delete this question?

I have a very very simple subscribe node. (Unfortunately searching the internet the usual examples use Strings, although a book of mine uses Ints)

The code is

```
import rospy
   
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge

import rosbag


def image_callback(msg):
    #print(msg.data.header)
    print(type(msg.data))
    print(len(msg.data))




def image_recorder():
    rospy.init_node('image_recorder', anonymous=True)
    sub = rospy.Subscriber('image_results',Image, image_callback)
    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        image_recorder()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Now, what is the problem?
The output of this is:

```
<type 'str'>
1184260
```

Why? The messages that we are receiving are Images, (that is why I try to do `msg.data.header` and fail!)

How can I recover the images?

And no, I do not need to use CvBridge to convert them to opencv Images. I just need the ROS images

Comment: **Never post answer in the question.** Post it as an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

msg is of type Image
therefore `msg.header` is the correct way to write it